# How to edit a value using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edit

I have this function: (I'm new with EF)

```
    public sis_user Save(sis_user user, bool edit)
    {
        if (edit)
        {
            //How to edit?
            sis_user userAux =_context.sis_user.FirstOrDefault(x => x.login == user.login);

            _context.SaveChanges();
            return user;
        }

        //To add.
        _context.sis_sis_user.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return user;
    }
```

I can add values, but I'm not sure how to edit a existing one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the property value that you want to be changed.

```
public sis_user Save(sis_user user, bool edit)
    {
        if (edit)
        {
            //How to edit?
            sis_user userAux =_context.sis_user.FirstOrDefault(x => x.login == user.login);
            userAux.Name = "Different Name";
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return user;
        }

        //To add.
        _context.sis_sis_user.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: You could since they are of same type assuming `user` has id that of `userAux` and there are no complex types contained in these objects.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the fields on the object you just pulled.

```
sis_user userAux =_context.sis_user.FirstOrDefault(x => x.login == user.login);

userAux.XXX = "Some Value";

_context.SaveChanges();
```